# Why is this FetchType.LAZY being ignored and all entities are being fetched on the query?

Tags: java, spring, set, spring-data, jpql

I am using Spring Boot 2 with Hibernate and I have an entity named `ItemCarga` with this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "rel_transp_carga", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_item_carga") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_transportadora") })
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private Set<Transportadora> transportadoras = new HashSet<Transportadora>();
```

Whey do a query using that entity on my repository, like this:

```
@Query("select e from ItemCarga e where e.cnpjCeramica = :cnpjCeramica and (e.dataInserido between :inicio and :fim) ")
List<ItemCarga> listarProdutosPorPeriodo(
        @Param("cnpjCeramica") String cnpjCeramica, 
        @Param("inicio") Date dataInicial, 
        @Param("fim") Date dataFinal, 
        Sort sort);
```

The result is a set of `ItemCarga` entity with the attribute `transportadoras` fetched with all its items.

It shouldn't it be null or empty?

Shouldn't be ignored since I didn't mention that attribute on my select?

Comment: How do you know all the `transportadoras` are fetched? Basically when you look at the collection with a debugger it will then lazily fetch the objects, if you print the content, the same. SO basically when you start looking at it, the collection will start to fill.

Comment: Good point, how do I know that it's not?? I mean, how to confirm that if I don't do anything to fetch is not being fetched?

Comment: If you look at the collection it will be fetched, that is the whole point of being lazy. Being lazy means fetch when needed. Don't look at it, don't try to use `size()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You did mention the attribute in the query: `select e from ItemCarga e`. This means you're fetching the whole `ItemCarga` entity. Since you defined `transportadoras` as `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, a proxy is created (the data is not fetched from the database).

If you're invoking the query withing transaction, you can iterate over the set, then hibernate will fetch the child entities (this often leads to n+1 select problem). If you try to access it outside of transaction, `LazyInitializationException` will be thrown.

Since it's just a hint for hibernate, you can make sure, the `Set` won't be fetched in a couple of ways:

1. by not querying for it, for example:

   ```
   @Query("select e.field1, e.field2 from ItemCarga e ...")
   List<Object[]> listarProdutosPorPeriodo...
   ```

   The downside is that you have to cast the results,
2. by using dto and query mapping. I won't describe it in detail, more you can find [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/),
3. by using projections - interfaces with getters and setters for the fields you want to fetch. More details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).

Comment: What to do to not fetch the whole `ItemCarga` entity? I mean, that `transportadoras` attribute should not be loaded.

Comment: Did you read my answer? It's not fetched from the database, only proxy is created.

Comment: I read, but that's not what is happening, that is exactly the problem, it is being fetched.

Comment: @franzfull ok, I get it, sorry, added some possible solutions